# Different value of sha256 on-chain than off-chain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I am using HFB 1.4.6, and I emit chaincode logs, which I capture one by one, to apply sha256 and base64 to each. However the sha256 result varies with respect to the sha256 off-chain verification.

This is the chaincode output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaEbB.png)

This is the online verification:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9MJN.png)

I have reproduce the same scenario of functions used in play.golang instance:
https://play.golang.org/p/2iVVKMMa7fA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue since I was omitting the '\n' character at the end of the log. So I have added the next line to remove the endline character:

```
logStringWoutN := strings.TrimSuffix(logString, "\n")
```